# How do I add associations with sequelize using an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a association with an async function but all it does is create both objects in the DB and fails at the association step, saying that addQuestion() does not exist. It works using a .then promise but that's a bit messy, in my opinion. The steps are as follows:

1. Find user, or create if doesn't exist.
2. Find question, or create if doesn't exist.
3. Add association between user and question.

The code is as follows:

```
    async function testDB() {
    const user = await db.user.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            username: 'Cow',
            password: 'fooBar',
            firstName: 'Bob',
            lastName: 'B',
            email: 'blah@email.com',
        },
    });

    if ((await user) === null) {
        console.log("User doesn't exist.");
    } else {
        const quest = await db.question.create({
            summary: 'Where am I?',
        });

        if ((await quest) === null) {
            console.log('No such question');
        } else {
            db.user.addQuestion(quest);
        }
    }
}
```

My model associations look like this:

user model:

```
            models.user.hasMany(models.question, {
                foreignKey: {
                    name: 'createdBy',
                },
                target: {
                    name: 'username',
                },
            });
            models.user.hasMany(models.answer, {
                foreignKey: {
                    name: 'createdBy',
                },
            });
        }
```

question model:

```
static associate(models) {
            models.question.belongsTo(models.user, {
                foreignKey: 'createdBy',
                target: 'username',
            });
            models.question.hasMany(models.answer);
        }
```

Comment: @Matt  Aye, I think so? I can't look at that because apparently I gotta buy it.

Comment: oh sorry that loaded a code example for me, not trying to sell their book so I'll delete it.  There's a sequelize github issue with it I was looking for but gave up....

Comment: Call associate after init like in `index.js` here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6524#issuecomment-329664805